# Query SQL by grouped expiration date

Tags: sql

*The below is a simplification of the query I am writing, but it simplifies it down to the part that I am not sure how to do.*

I have a table of purchases. In this table, there is a ifrprodid, cgroup, and dexpire columns among others. If the cgroup column contains an 'M', then it is a grouped item. All of the ifrprodids from that group will match the cgroup ifrprodid.

```
ifrprodid   cgroup   dexpire  ...
5                    1/1/14
8           M        1/1/14
5           M        1/1/15
8                    1/1/15
8                    1/1/14
```

What I need to do is select all of the columns where the ifrprodid matches an ifrprodid where the cgroup is M and the dexpire has passed.

In other words, since the second column above has a cgroup of M and an expiration date of 1/1/14, I need to include rows with an ifrprodid of 8. However, since row three, the other row with a cgroup of M, has not expired, I should not get any rows with an ifrprodid of 5.

Thus, my results should look like this:

```
ifrprodid    cgroup     dexpire     ...
8            M          1/1/14
8                       1/1/15
8                       1/1/14
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you select all expired groups:

`select ifrprodid from prod_table where cgroup='M' and dexpire < ?`

Now we need all products in these groups, so with ifprodid in this list. There are two options:

1. Join: `select p.* from prod_table p inner join prod_table g on p.ifrprodid=g.ifrprodid where g.cgroup='M' and g.dexpire < ?`
2. Subselect: `select * from prod_table where ifrprodid in (select ifrprodid from prod_table where cgroup='M' and dexpire < ?)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming generic SQL:

```
select *
from table
where ifprodid in (
  select ifprodid 
  from table
  where cgroup = 'M'
  and dexpire < today()
  )
```